# Question regarding two contact forms in my store

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, email, contact-us, extensions

I have a module for a custom contact form which is working great.

Now I want a seperate contact form for customers to place returns. I figured to use the default contact form magento provides. I've edited the associated template file and email template within admin, but I can't figure out to how assign an email that it will be sent to.

Within **admin -> general -> contacts** I only see the ability to select an email for one form (which is now the custom contact form):

http://linenwoods.com/testing/Capture.PNG

How can I select an email for the default form as well? Or is this not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your custom contact form overrides `Mage_Contacts`, which uses settings from `admin -> general -> contacts`. If this is the case, you will not be able to use separate emails for the custom form and the return form you want to use.

You can create an extension similar to `Mage_Contacts` that will have its own setting in the admins. Are you familiar with making extensions?

Comment: You guessed correctly. While I am familiar with making an extension, I haven't actually done it before so I'm afraid that won't be possible. Thanks for the confirmation though.